# pivot table returns zeros

Tags: sql, null, pivot

could you please help me with pivot table. For some reason it returns all zeros!
my code is

```
SELECT VendorID, ['Y']  , ['N']
FROM   
(SELECT 
VendorSiteID,
Local,
VendorID  
FROM [DB]) p  
PIVOT  
(  
COUNT (VendorSiteID)  
FOR Local IN  
( ['Y'], ['N'] )  
) AS pvt  
order by [VendorID]
```

my sample data is

| VendorID | VendorSiteID | Local |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | Y |
| 456 | DEF | N |
| 789 | GHI | N |

Expected result:

| VendorID | Y | N |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 |  |
| 456 |  | 1 |
| 789 |  | 1 |

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @Charlieface could you please take a look?

Comment: I had to remove quotes and everything is working!

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove quotes and everything is working!!